# How to install OpenLayers plugin on QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am a new user of QGIS, and I just downloaded the version 2.4 on Windows 7/32 bits. And I seem to encounter several problems:

1. I cannot install OpenLayers plugin
2. In the "Plugins" tab under "Manage and install plugins" I have only 3 windows "All", "Installed" and "Settings" and it is missing "Not installed"...and here either I open the "all" or "installed" window I have the same number of plugins, that is 23...and I cannot make any modifications like "upgrade" or "uninstall" etc...

Dos any one have an idea what is happening with my QGIS version? Or if I did something wrong when installing...I know that I just followed the easy installation for new users...

Answer (score 4):

- download the latest version from here: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/
- unzip to your qgis python plugins directory

  - on linux: ~/.qgis2/python/plugins
  - on windows: %USERPROFILE%\.qgis2\python\plugins
- restart qgis
- now you can enable it